# What is the maximum/minimum temperature humans can survive at for an extended period of time, and what rate does the body temperature change at?

Tags: temperature

3 questions:

1. At what rate does the body temperature of a human change at? That is, assuming the outside temperature is x, is there some sort of formula that can determine how long it takes for the human body to reach any temperature above or equal to x? I understand this is quite variable, but any data will be useful.
2. a) What are the harshest conditions currently on Earth that we can survive at (That is, the maximum temperatures people actively live at every day for a period of years, and the minimum temperatures they do so).

   b) In what ways have their bodies adapted to allow them to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully you're not asking this because of the covid-heat-yourself-to-56C-cure nonsense.

Comment: Why would that be the reason .... *starts sweating because he's in a 60C home and doesn't know if he's going to die so he hoped the bio stack exchange would*

Comment: This depends a lot on what kind of clothing and tools the human has.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, each question should be posted separately — this improves the chances that you will get answers for each question and makes the answers more accessible for future users. ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 